# Ending position out of bounds: -1\n

Tags: apex

I'm getting this error when I creating a record can anyone please help me to resolve the issue

> error = 1;
>      message = "Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0Q0n000002FcS9EAK; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, III_Borrower_InfoTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate\n\ncaused by: System.StringException: Ending position out of bounds: -1\n\nClass.SL_Integration_SFLoan_Processor.getAllFields: line 118, column 1\nClass.SL_Integration_SFLoan_Processor.formSOQLQuery: line 95, column 1\nClass.SL_Integration_SFLoan_Processor.createActionEventRecords: line 24, column 1\nClass.SL_Integration_SFLoan_Processor.: line 14, column 1\nClass.SL_Loan_Handler.processLoanFromBorrower: line 324, column 1\nClass.BorrowerPairAfterUpdateTriggerHandler.mainEntry: line 17, column 1\nClass.TriggerDispatcherBase.execute: line 84, column 1\nClass.III_Borrower_InfoTriggerDispatcher.afterUpdate: line 74, column 1\nClass.TriggerFactory.execute: line 52, column 1\nClass.TriggerFactory.createTriggerDispatcher: line 22, column 1\nTrigger.III_Borrower_InfoTrigger: line 16, column 1: []";
>   }

Borrower Trigger :

```
trigger III_Borrower_InfoTrigger on III_Borrower_Info__c (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    if(TriggerState.isActive('BorrowerPairTrigger')){
        TriggerFactory.createTriggerDispatcher(III_Borrower_Info__c.sObjectType);
    }
}
```

III_Borrower_InfoTriggerDispatcher:

```
public class III_Borrower_InfoTriggerDispatcher extends TriggerDispatcherBase {
    private static Boolean isBeforeInsertProcessing = false;
    private static Boolean isBeforeUpdateProcessing = false;
    private static Boolean isAfterInsertProcessing = false;
    private static Boolean isAfterUpdateProcessing = false; 
    private static Boolean isAfterDeleteProcessing = false;
    /** 
    * @description Called by the trigger framework to carry out the actions before the records are inserted. If there is an       
    *               existing call running on the same context, the rentrant call will utilize the handler that was created
    *               in the original call.
    * @param TriggerParameters Contains the trigger parameters which includes the records that is getting inserted.
    */
    public virtual override void beforeInsert(TriggerParameters tp) {
        if(!isBeforeInsertProcessing) {
            isBeforeInsertProcessing = true;
            execute(new BorrowerPairBeforeInsertTriggerHandler(), tp, TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.beforeInsert);
            isBeforeInsertProcessing = false;
        }
        else execute(null, tp, TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.beforeInsert);
    }

    /** 
    * @description Called by the trigger framework to carry out the actions before the records are updated. If there is an
    *               existing call running on the same context, the rentrant call will utilize the handler that was created
    *               in the original call.
    * @param TriggerParameters Contains the trigger parameters which includes the records that is getting updated.
    */
    public virtual override void beforeUpdate(TriggerParameters tp) {
        if(!isBeforeUpdateProcessing) {
            isBeforeUpdateProcessing = true;
            execute(new BorrowerPairBeforeUpdateTriggerHandler(), tp, TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.beforeUpdate);
            isBeforeUpdateProcessing = false;
        }
        else execute(null, tp, TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.beforeUpdate);
    }

    /** 
    * @description Called by the trigger framework to carry out the actions after the record(s) are created. If there is an
    *               existing call running on the same context, the rentrant call will utilize the handler that was created
    *               in the original call.
    * @param TriggerParameters Contains the trigger parameters which includes the record(s) that got created.
    */
    public virtual override void afterInsert(TriggerParameters tp) {
        if(!isAfterInsertProcessing) {
            isAfterInsertProcessing = true;
            execute(new BorrowerPairAfterInsertTriggerHandler(), tp, TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.afterInsert);
            isAfterInsertProcessing = false;
        }
        else execute(null, tp, TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.afterInsert);
    }


    public virtual override void afterUpdate(TriggerParameters tp) {
        if(!isAfterUpdateProcessing) {
            isAfterUpdateProcessing = true;
            execute(new BorrowerPairAfterUpdateTriggerHandler(), tp, TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.afterUpdate);
            isAfterUpdateProcessing = false;
        }
        else execute(null, tp, TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.afterUpdate);
    }

    public virtual override void afterDelete(TriggerParameters tp) {
        if(!isAfterDeleteProcessing) {
            isAfterDeleteProcessing = true;
            execute(new BorrowerPairAfterDeleteTriggerHandler(), tp, TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.afterUpdate);
            isAfterDeleteProcessing = false;
        }
        else execute(null, tp, TriggerParameters.TriggerEvent.afterDelete);
    }
}
```

SL_Integration_SFLoan_Processor :

```
global with sharing class SL_Integration_SFLoan_Processor  {
Set<ID> IDsToProcess {get; set;}

    global SL_Integration_SFLoan_Processor(){

    } 

    global SL_Integration_SFLoan_Processor(Set<ID> IDSet){  

        if (SL_App__c.getOrgDefaults().Integration_UserID__c == null) {return;}
        if (UserInfo.getUserId() == SL_App__c.getOrgDefaults().Integration_UserID__c) {return;}

        IDsToProcess = IDSet;
        createActionEventRecords();
        system.debug('=======SL_Integration_SFLoan_Processor=');
    }


    global  void createActionEventRecords(){
        boolean  bppayload = false;
        Map<ID, String> CCMLoanIDtoJSONPayload = new Map<Id,String>();
        List<SL_Action_Event__c> ActionEventList = new List<SL_Action_Event__c>();
        system.debug('=======createActionEventRecords=');
        //gets all fields from both objects
        List<CCM_Loan__c> returnedCCMLoans  = Database.query(formSOQLQuery('CCM_Loan__c', 'WHERE ID in :IDsToProcess')); 
        system.debug('=======returnedCCMLoans='+returnedCCMLoans);
        system.debug('=======returnedCCMLoans='+IDsToProcess);
        List<III_Borrower_Info__c> returnedBorrowerPairs = Database.query(formSOQLQuery('III_Borrower_Info__c', 'WHERE CCM_Loan__c in :IDsToProcess'));
        if(!returnedBorrowerPairs.isEmpty()){
            for(III_Borrower_Info__c borrowerPair : returnedBorrowerPairs){
                if(borrowerPair.Process_SL_Action_Event__c == false){
                    bppayload = true;
                }
            }
        }
        Map<String, List<III_Borrower_Info__c>> loanIDtoBorrowerPairs =  new Map<String, List<III_Borrower_Info__c>>();
        system.debug('=======createActionEventRecords=');
        //associating borrower pair lists with loans
         for(III_Borrower_Info__c borrowerPair : returnedBorrowerPairs){
            if(loanIDtoBorrowerPairs.get(borrowerPair.CCM_Loan__c) == null ){
                List<III_Borrower_Info__c> pairList = new  List<III_Borrower_Info__c>();
                loanIDtoBorrowerPairs.put(borrowerPair.CCM_Loan__c, pairList);
            }
            loanIDtoBorrowerPairs.get(borrowerPair.CCM_Loan__c).add( borrowerPair);
        }
        system.debug('=======loanIDtoBorrowerPairs='+loanIDtoBorrowerPairs);
        //building loans and borrower pairs payload
        for (CCM_Loan__c ccmLoanIterator : returnedCCMLoans){
            SL_CCM_Global.SL_Encompass_ApplicationMessage newPayload =SL_Integration_Loan_Builder.buildApplicationMessage(ccmLoanIterator);
                system.debug('newPayload======================'+newPayload);
                if(loanIDtoBorrowerPairs.containsKey(ccmLoanIterator.ID)){
                    if(!loanIDtoBorrowerPairs.get(ccmLoanIterator.ID).isEmpty() ){
                        for(III_Borrower_Info__c borrowerPair : loanIDtoBorrowerPairs.get(ccmLoanIterator.ID)){
                            newPayload.BorrowerPair.add(SL_Integration_Loan_Builder.buildBorrowerPairInfo(borrowerPair));
                        }
                    }
                }
            string JSONPayload = JSON.serialize(newPayload, true);
            CCMLoanIDtoJSONPayload.put(ccmLoanIterator.ID, JSONPayload);
       }
        map<Id,SL_Action_Event__c> mapSLActionevent = new map<id,SL_Action_Event__c>();
        list<SL_Action_Event__c> lstSAE = new List<SL_Action_Event__c>();
        system.debug('====CCMLoanIDtoJSONPayloadCCMLoanIDtoJSONPayloadCCMLoanIDtoJSONPayload======='+CCMLoanIDtoJSONPayload.keyset());
        if(!CCMLoanIDtoJSONPayload.isEmpty() && bppayload == true){
            lstSAE = [select Id,name,CCM_Loan__c,Payload__c from SL_Action_Event__c where CCM_Loan__c in:CCMLoanIDtoJSONPayload.keySet() and Event_Type__c = 'Loan'];            
        }
        SYSTEM.debug('=================lstSAE==='+lstSAE.size()+'==='+lstSAE);
        for(SL_Action_Event__c objSL:lstSAE){ 
            system.debug('=====new length======='+CCMLoanIDtoJSONPayload.get(objSL.CCM_Loan__c).length());
             system.debug('=====payload length======='+objSL.Payload__c.length());
            if(CCMLoanIDtoJSONPayload.get(objSL.CCM_Loan__c) != null && CCMLoanIDtoJSONPayload.get(objSL.CCM_Loan__c).length() >= objSL.Payload__c.length()){
                system.debug('inside ==============');
                objSL.Payload__c = CCMLoanIDtoJSONPayload.get(objSL.CCM_Loan__c); 
                mapSLActionevent.put(objSL.CCM_Loan__c,objSL);
            }
        }
        //creating list of action events, adding payloads to them
        SYSTEM.debug('=================mapSLActionevent==='+mapSLActionevent);
        SYSTEM.debug('bppayload======'+ bppayload);
        for (ID IDIterator : CCMLoanIDtoJSONPayload.keySet()){
            system.debug('========'+CCMLoanIDtoJSONPayload);
            system.debug('=========='+ mapSLActionevent.get(IDIterator));
            if(bppayload){
                if(mapSLActionevent.get(IDIterator) != null){
                    system.debug('inside Existing Map ==============');
                    ActionEventList.add(mapSLActionevent.get(IDIterator));
                }else if(mapSLActionevent.get(IDIterator) == null){ 
                    system.debug('inside New Map ==============');
                    SL_Action_Event__c newActionEvent = new SL_Action_Event__c();
                    newActionEvent.Event_Type__c = 'Loan';
                    newActionEvent.CCM_Loan__c = IDIterator;
                    newActionEvent.Payload__c = CCMLoanIDtoJSONPayload.get(IDIterator);
                    newActionEvent.IC_Primed__c = SL_App__c.getOrgDefaults().Default_Primed_Value_for_Callouts_to_CCM__c;
                    // newActionEvent.CCM_Loan_File__c = 'a0Kn0000001kcZ2'; // just testing purpose added and once done with testing will make dynamic
                    ActionEventList.add(newActionEvent);
                }
            }
        }
        system.debug('=======ActionEventList='+ActionEventList);
        if(!ActionEventList.isEmpty()){
            upsert ActionEventList;
        }
    }



 public  String formSOQLQuery(String sobjectname, String strCondition){
        String strQuery = 'Select ';

        if(sobjectname != NUll && sobjectname != ''){

                strQuery += getAllFields(sobjectname)+',Owner.Name From ' + sobjectname+ ' ' +strCondition;

        }
        return strQuery;
    }

     public   String getAllFields(String sobjectname){
        if(!Schema.getGlobalDescribe().containsKey(sobjectname)) return '';

        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sobjectname).getDescribe().SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

        List<String> accessiblefields = new List<String>();

        for(Schema.SObjectField field : fields.values()){
            if(field.getDescribe().isAccessible())
                accessiblefields.add(field.getDescribe().getName());
        }
        system.debug('====accessiblefields========='+accessiblefields);
        String allfields='';

        for(String fieldname : accessiblefields)
            allfields += fieldname+',';
        system.debug('====allfields========='+allfields);
        allfields = allfields.subString(0,allfields.length()-1);

        return allfields;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does any of this even do? Seems like entirely too many unnecessary layers of abstraction which just bloats CPU usage and the code shown doesn't appear to actually do anything (what is hiding in execute method).

Answer (score 1):

This is way too much code. When you're dealing with an issue like this, you need to do your best to produce a **minimal example**: the smallest possible unit of code and input data that produces the issue. You've included a great deal of irrelevant code in your question, making it harder for people to answer you.

The stack trace provides a guide to where to look. The proximate location of the error is `Class.SL_Integration_SFLoan_Processor.getAllFields: line 118`. Your first recourse to create a minimal example would be to determine, via `System.debug()`, use of the debugger, Anonymous Apex, and so on, what inputs to `getAllFields()` produce this issue. Since that method has no side effects and no dependencies, it's easy to isolate.

I believe that your issue lies here:

```
 public   String getAllFields(String sobjectname){
    // <code snipped>
    String allfields='';

    for(String fieldname : accessiblefields)
        allfields += fieldname+',';
    system.debug('====allfields========='+allfields);
    allfields = allfields.subString(0,allfields.length()-1);

    return allfields;
}
```

When `accessiblefields` is empty (perhaps the running user has no access to this sObject at all), this will result in the observed error, because `allfields.length()` will be zero after the end of the `for` loop. Hence, you're asking for `subString(0, -1)`, resulting in `System.StringException: Ending position out of bounds: -1`.

You should implement logic to handle this case, perhaps by returning `'Id'` if `accessiblefields` is empty.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused by me regarding the post i'm very new to coding I have  no clue where the error resides that was the reason for posting the entire code can you help me with what logic should be written

Comment: Priyanka, welcome to SFSE - please don't worry about it; this is a chance to learn how to debug. I've provided some pointers above that you can apply next time. I've made a suggestion about one possibility, but you'll need to ensure any changes match your requirements, and handle updating the code. (SFSE doesn't generally *write* code, we help with specific issues).